# ¿Cómo comparar correctamente cadenas con strcmp?

Tags: c

Estoy intentando comparar una cadena llamada *CUA* con valores predeclarados: *( 12345 )* con una cadena llamada *clave* que está siendo capturada con el `scanf` (ya también intenté con `gets`) pero no me está arrojando el resultado deseado. Al escanear *12345* en *clave* debería de arrojarme **0** en la comparación de ambas cadenas e imprimirme el mensaje "BIENVENIDO ADMINISTRADOR" pero en su lugar toma el else.

```c
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<windows.h>


 
    void main(){

    int i;
    char op;
    char CUA[5]="12345", clave[5];


    printf("%s", CUA); //Aquí estoy verificando que la cadena que contiene la clave este llenada correctamente

    do{
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ________________________________\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t||                              ||\n");        //Presentacion
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t||       TRICO PAQUETERIAS      ||\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t||                              ||\n");
    printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t --------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("Bienvenido a TRICO PAQUETERIAS.\n\n\n");
    printf("1.  Control de Usuario Administrador.\n(Seleccione esta opcion si es un administrador autorizado.)\n\n");
    printf("2.  Manejo de datos como Usuario Autorizado.\n(Seleccione esta opcion si es un trabajador autorizado.)\n\n");
    printf("3.  Ratrear un paquete.\n(Seleccione esta opcion si desea rastrear un paquete mediante un numero de guia.)\n\n");
    printf("4.  Salir del programa.\n\n\n");
    printf("Seleccione una de las opciones: ");
    scanf(" %c", &op);
    printf("\n");
    while(getchar() != '\n'){
        getchar();
    }
    printf("\n");

    switch(op){
        case '1':
            printf("\n|     Ingrese la clave unica de Administrador:    |\n\n");
            scanf("%[^\n]", clave);


            if((strcmp(CUA,clave)) == 0){
                printf("\nBIENVENIDO ADMINISTRADOR\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("\nNO TIENES LAS CREDENCIALES NECESARIAS\n");
            }

            break;

        case '2':
            printf("j\n\n");
            break;

        case '3':
            printf("p\n\n");
            break;

        case '4':
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nELIJA UNA OPCION VALIDA\n\n");
            break;
    }
    }while(op!='4');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu empleo de la función `strcmp()` es correcto, porque no tiene mucho misterio, pero estás definiendo el tamaño del array de una manera errónea. Si estás inicializando el array `CUA` con un valor no es necesario que le indiques el tamaño. De igual modo, el array `clave` dale más espacio (sin pasarse) del que vas a necesitar, por si el usuario ingresa más de 5 caracteres por error. Todo esto lo habrías podido comprobar si ingresas un `printf` arrojando el valor de `CUA` y `clave` una vez ingresados, donde  `CUA` tomaba el valor `1234512345` y en cambio `clave` correspondía al valor que el usuario ingresaba.

El código que buscas puede ser algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_CHARACTERS  10


void main(){

    int i;
    char op;
    char CUA[]="12345", clave[MAX_CHARACTERS];


    printf("%s", CUA); //Aquí estoy verificando que la cadena que contiene la clave este llenada correctamente

    do{
        printf("Seleccione una de las opciones: ");
        scanf(" %c", &op);
        printf("\n");
        while(getchar() != '\n'){
            getchar();
        }
        printf("\n");

        switch(op){
            case '1':
                printf("\n|     Ingrese la clave unica de Administrador:    |\n\n");
                scanf("%s", clave);

                if((strcmp(CUA,clave)) == 0){
                    printf("\nBIENVENIDO ADMINISTRADOR\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf("\nNO TIENES LAS CREDENCIALES NECESARIAS\n");
                }
            break;

            default:
                printf("\nELIJA UNA OPCION VALIDA\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }while(op!='4');

}
```

He quitado varias opciones del `switch-case` para simplificar el copy-paste. Pero tu duda quedaría resuelta.